Using NetMeasurements for basic neural network
I have a neural network that works fine, but I would like to obtain some results on the Validation Set which provides some metrics on the performance of the training. I am obtaining some strange output when using the NetMeasurements built-in function. I would expect some real numbers between 0 and 1, but instead I get an accuracy of 1 (doesn't seem plausible) and then some numbers and arrows. Can anyone advise on the reason for this, many thanks.
In the code I start by providing the training and validation data sets, I then train it and finally I attempt to analyze the validation set using NetMeasurements:
(*Training and Validation Data*)
TrainingData = {{9994, 6} -> 1, {9964, 36} -> 2, {9905, 95} -> 
    3, {9852, 148} -> 4, {9735, 265} -> 5, {9619, 381} -> 
    6, {9541, 459} -> 7, {9356, 644} -> 8, {9219, 781} -> 
    9, {9063, 937} -> 10, {8879, 1121} -> 11, {8644, 1356} -> 
    12, {8373, 1627} -> 13, {8144, 1856} -> 14, {8001, 1999} -> 
    15, {7690, 2310} -> 16, {7506, 2494} -> 17, {7152, 2848} -> 
    18, {6864, 3136} -> 19, {6634, 3366} -> 20, {6219, 3781} -> 
    21, {5975, 4025} -> 22, {5598, 4402} -> 23, {5331, 4669} -> 
    24, {4972, 5028} -> 25, {4693, 5307} -> 26, {4433, 5567} -> 
    27, {4019, 5981} -> 28, {3806, 6194} -> 29, {3398, 6602} -> 
    30, {3131, 6869} -> 31, {2888, 7112} -> 32, {2644, 7356} -> 
    33, {2311, 7689} -> 34, {2012, 7988} -> 35, {1778, 8222} -> 
    36, {1544, 8456} -> 37, {1327, 8673} -> 38, {1151, 8849} -> 
    39, {963, 9037} -> 40, {774, 9226} -> 41, {590, 9410} -> 
    42, {479, 9521} -> 43, {360, 9640} -> 44, {265, 9735} -> 
    45, {160, 9840} -> 46, {80, 9920} -> 47, {53, 9947} -> 
    48, {12, 9988} -> 49, {0, 10000} -> 50};

ValidationData = {{9991, 9} -> 1, {9959, 41} -> 2, {9902, 98} -> 
    3, {9849, 151} -> 4, {9764, 236} -> 5, {9623, 377} -> 
    6, {9497, 503} -> 7, {9342, 658} -> 8, {9213, 787} -> 
    9, {9073, 927} -> 10, {8826, 1174} -> 11, {8585, 1415} -> 
    12, {8420, 1580} -> 13, {8166, 1834} -> 14, {7926, 2074} -> 
    15, {7708, 2292} -> 16, {7508, 2492} -> 17, {7064, 2936} -> 
    18, {6758, 3242} -> 19, {6577, 3423} -> 20, {6304, 3696} -> 
    21, {5872, 4128} -> 22, {5661, 4339} -> 23, {5228, 4772} -> 
    24, {4936, 5064} -> 25, {4703, 5297} -> 26, {4387, 5613} -> 
    27, {4061, 5939} -> 28, {3786, 6214} -> 29, {3354, 6646} -> 
    30, {3227, 6773} -> 31, {2877, 7123} -> 32, {2661, 7339} -> 
    33, {2360, 7640} -> 34, {2033, 7967} -> 35, {1828, 8172} -> 
    36, {1552, 8448} -> 37, {1372, 8628} -> 38, {1138, 8862} -> 
    39, {958, 9042} -> 40, {770, 9230} -> 41, {612, 9388} -> 
    42, {479, 9521} -> 43, {355, 9645} -> 44, {259, 9741} -> 
    45, {160, 9840} -> 46, {81, 9919} -> 47, {36, 9964} -> 
    48, {14, 9986} -> 49, {0, 10000} -> 50};

(*Neural network architecture*)
net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[300], BatchNormalizationLayer[], 
    ElementwiseLayer["ReLU"], LinearLayer[300], 
    BatchNormalizationLayer[], ElementwiseLayer["ReLU"], 
    LinearLayer[50], SoftmaxLayer[] } ];

(*Training the network*)
trainedNet = 
 NetTrain[net, TrainingData, ValidationSet -> ValidationData, 
  BatchSize -> Automatic, MaxTrainingRounds -> 10000, 
  LearningRate -> 0.01]

(*Measurements of Validation Set*)
measurements = 
 NetMeasurements[trainedNet, 
  ValidationData, {"Accuracy", "Precision", "Recall", "F1Score"}]
{1., <|1 -> 1., 2 -> 1., 3 -> 1., 4 -> 1., 5 -> 1., 6 -> 1., 7 -> 1., 
  8 -> 1., 9 -> 1., 10 -> 1., 11 -> 1., 12 -> 1., 13 -> 1., 14 -> 1., 
  15 -> 1., 16 -> 1., 17 -> 1., 18 -> 1., 19 -> 1., 20 -> 1., 
  21 -> 1., 22 -> 1., 23 -> 1., 24 -> 1., 25 -> 1., 26 -> 1., 
  27 -> 1., 28 -> 1., 29 -> 1., 30 -> 1., 31 -> 1., 32 -> 1., 
  33 -> 1., 34 -> 1., 35 -> 1., 36 -> 1., 37 -> 1., 38 -> 1., 
  39 -> 1., 40 -> 1., 41 -> 1., 42 -> 1., 43 -> 1., 44 -> 1., 
  45 -> 1., 46 -> 1., 47 -> 1., 48 -> 1., 49 -> 1., 
  50 -> 1.|>, <|1 -> 1., 2 -> 1., 3 -> 1., 4 -> 1., 5 -> 1., 6 -> 1., 
  7 -> 1., 8 -> 1., 9 -> 1., 10 -> 1., 11 -> 1., 12 -> 1., 13 -> 1., 
  14 -> 1., 15 -> 1., 16 -> 1., 17 -> 1., 18 -> 1., 19 -> 1., 
  20 -> 1., 21 -> 1., 22 -> 1., 23 -> 1., 24 -> 1., 25 -> 1., 
  26 -> 1., 27 -> 1., 28 -> 1., 29 -> 1., 30 -> 1., 31 -> 1., 
  32 -> 1., 33 -> 1., 34 -> 1., 35 -> 1., 36 -> 1., 37 -> 1., 
  38 -> 1., 39 -> 1., 40 -> 1., 41 -> 1., 42 -> 1., 43 -> 1., 
  44 -> 1., 45 -> 1., 46 -> 1., 47 -> 1., 48 -> 1., 49 -> 1., 
  50 -> 1.|>, <|1 -> 1., 2 -> 1., 3 -> 1., 4 -> 1., 5 -> 1., 6 -> 1., 
  7 -> 1., 8 -> 1., 9 -> 1., 10 -> 1., 11 -> 1., 12 -> 1., 13 -> 1., 
  14 -> 1., 15 -> 1., 16 -> 1., 17 -> 1., 18 -> 1., 19 -> 1., 
  20 -> 1., 21 -> 1., 22 -> 1., 23 -> 1., 24 -> 1., 25 -> 1., 
  26 -> 1., 27 -> 1., 28 -> 1., 29 -> 1., 30 -> 1., 31 -> 1., 
  32 -> 1., 33 -> 1., 34 -> 1., 35 -> 1., 36 -> 1., 37 -> 1., 
  38 -> 1., 39 -> 1., 40 -> 1., 41 -> 1., 42 -> 1., 43 -> 1., 
  44 -> 1., 45 -> 1., 46 -> 1., 47 -> 1., 48 -> 1., 49 -> 1., 
  50 -> 1.|>}


If you add a NetDecoder to your softmax layer that returns the position of the largest (most probable class) element, you'll see the ValidationSet is perfectly reconstructed. I.e. in your definition of net replace SoftmaxLayer[] with SoftmaxLayer["Output" -> dec] with
dec = NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[50]}];
